# Merging of columns in text file

Tags: perl, shell, unix, scripting

Input of the text file

```
A | 1 | def | 1432
A | 1 | ffr | 1234
A | 1 | dfs | 3241
A | 2 | asf | 2213
```

Desired Output

```
A | 1 | def 1432,ffr 1234,dfs 3241
A | 2 | asf 2213
```

Merging values related to **2nd column** in a single row

Comment: I want the desired output as shown above.

Comment: What do you do with "B | 1 | aaa | 111" in the sample input?  Is it merged with the "A | 1" line or not?  What does "related" mean?  Do you print multiple copies of duplicated text?  Providing a limited sample does not provide sufficient detail.

Comment: 1st column remains the same (constant). The merging depends only on 2nd column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And here is a Perl attempt:

```
perl -F'\s+\|\s+' -alne '
$a{$F[1]} .= "$F[2] $F[3],";
END {
  $_ = "A | $_ | $a{$_}", s/,$//, print for sort keys %a;
}' FILE
```

Comment: Just checked - it gives your example output from your example input.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not well specified, but here's a step towards a solution:

```
awk -F\| '{  a[$1 "|" $2] = a[$1 "|" $2 ] "," $3 $4 }
     END { for( x in a ) print x a[x]}' input |
     sed 's/,/|/'  # Trim leading comma
```

This will incorrectly delete the first comma in either of the first 2 columns instead of the incorrectly inserted leading comma in the 3rd column of output, and sorts on both of the first 2 columns rather than just the 2nd. Also, the order of the output will be different than the input.  There are probably other issues, but this may help.

Comment: I need to group by the 2nd col. and print 3rd nd 4th col. as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS = " \\| "; OFS = SUBSEP = " | " }
    {
        val[$1,$2] = val[$1,$2] sep[$1,$2] $3 " " $4
        sep[$1,$2] = ","
    }
    END { for (key in val) print key, val[key] }
'
```

This will likely not preserve the order of the input. Also, it uses both the 1st and 2nd columns as the key, but as you say the 1st column does not change it is irrelevant.